# Extract chlorophyll a data from multiple netCDF files with multiple area of interest in python

Tags: python, netcdf4

I have a variety of chlorophyll_a netCDF files.
I attempted to modify python coding from some examples that I have found, but it did not work because the example coding using the files contained the time and date data.
It's possible that I'm new to this coding!!

So I would like to explain about my data;

1. I downloaded 365 chlorophyll_a files.

e.g. ['A2020001.L3m_DAY_CHL.x_chlor_a.nc', 'A2020002.L3m_DAY_CHL.x_chlor_a.nc', 'A2020003.L3m_DAY_CHL.x_chlor_a.nc', 'A2020004.L3m_DAY_CHL.x_chlor_a.nc', 'A2020005.L3m_DAY_CHL.x_chlor_a.nc', 'A2020006.L3m_DAY_CHL.x_chlor_a.nc'...'A2020365.L3m_DAY_CHL.x_chlor_a.nc']

2. One file contains one day's value. chlorophyll a, lat, long, and palette are all contained within a single file.

e.g. dict_keys(['chlor_a', 'lat', 'lon', 'palette'])

3. I'd want to combine all of the files and categorize them by 1-365 days (I need chlorophyll_a data in 365 days at all coordinates).
4. There is no time or date data in files but the date is displayed in the file name
   e.g.'A2020001.L3m_DAY_CHL.x_chlor_a.nc'

(I have tried to create an empty data frame with 356 days in the first column already, but I do not know how to fill the chlorophyll_a data at each day and each coordinate to my empty data frame).

e.g. code

```
date_start ='01-01-2020'
date_end ='31-12-2020'
date_range = pd.date_range(start= str(date_start),end =str(date_end), freq ='D') 
print(date_range)
```

5. Then I want to extract the chlorophyll_a data from the various positions of interest after combining 365 files together (I prepared the area of interest in CSV file).
   In this step, I can extract only one position from one netCDF file!!

I'm hoping you'll be able to offer some advice.
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I would suggest adding a time variable to the data i.e. for all the files and then open the dataset either by xarray or something similar.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am studying how to use xarray!!